# How to deauthorize computer with iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Lets say I have moved to another computer but haven't had a chance to deauthroize the computer I just reformatted, is there a way from your iTunes account to manage authorized computers?

Comment: Which operational system are you using on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

Apple will only allow you to deauthorize all of your computers when you have 5/5 registered and only once a year. Unfortunately, they do not allow individual deauthorizations when you don't deauthorize a computer in iTunes when reformatting :( I have tried to do this myself.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to deauthorize from an iPhone. However, what you can do is, from your computer, go to your iTunes account (from inside of iTunes). There will be an option in there to clear you authorize list. Do that, then reauthorize any computers that need it.